# Timeseries data on EventHubs Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub, azure-timeseries-insights

Editing my question.

I have a made up timeseries data with past and future timestamps in json format and I want to send it to Event Hubs so that I can use it as a source for Time Series Insights application.

I want to view that based on the data timestamp and not when it was enqueued.

The following screenshot of the timeseries insights shows 338 events clubbed together as one dot, 
[image]

while the JSON file or event data was like the below, with their own timestamps.

```
"Location":"XXXXX",
"EquipmentID": "XXXXXX",
"Events":[
{"Timestamp": "2018-04-06T12:45:00Z",...}
{"Timestamp": "2018-04-06T12:45:01Z",...}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: oh sorry if I gave that impression. I am not asking for code. I am asking for a suggestion. I already got the sample code from the various MS Azure documentation online and have sent json files to EventHubs too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify Timestamp property name as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/time-series-insights-send-events#create-time-series-insights-event-source). In you case the value of Timestamp property name should be Events.Timestamp since this will be the name of the indexed property after flattening.

Comment: Yes. I was about to say that. I was giving it explicitly in the property name as Timestamp and so it was taking the current timestamp instead of the one I mentioned in the json. Thank you.